# Dividing between tensor in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm beginner in keras.

What i want to do is, dividing every element of tensor with values in other tensor.

for example, dimension changes of this computation would be..

(1000, 100, 30, 30) / (1000, 100, 1, 1) -> (1000, 100, 30, 30)

How can I do this?

additional info)

What I actually want to do is, fix first code to have same dimension with second. Anyone knows proper way to do it? (Using theano as backend)

```
normalize_rate = 0.5
max_val = K.max(x, axis=(2,3))
normalized = x / (max_val * normalize_rate)
square_normalized = K.square(normalized)
return K.mean(square_normalized, axis = (2,3))
```

and

```
return K.mean(x, axis = (2, 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Lambda layer in the model and just divide normally:

```
tensor1 = output_of_a_layer_or_input1
tensor2 = output_of_a_layer_or_input2

divResult = Lambda(lambda x: x[0]/x[1])([tensor1,tensor2])
```

Comment: I add additional info in my questions.  It would help me a lot if you check it.